# Trouble running Ubuntu terminal command on files on external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, java, linux-terminal

I'm having difficulty looping a command in the Ubuntu terminal over files held on an external hard drive. When I move a subset of the files onto my main disk and adjust the path accordingly it works fine. Additionally, simpler commands (i.e., ls) work just fine on the external hard drive. 
Here is my command:

```
for i in /media/ij/EXT/RNA\ seq\ data\ 2018\ Genewiz/DJ1807193/DJ1807193/*.fastq.gz;
 do java -jar ~/RNAseq/trimmomatic-0.36.jar SE 
-phred33 $i /media/ij/EXT/trimmed/${i##*/} ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-SE.fa:2:30:10; done
```

(returns added for readability)

The external drive is formatted in ntfs if that helps- from what I've read, it shouldn't make a difference.
Thanks for any help/suggestions you can provide, and let me know what other info might help you help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the habit to quote the file names (especially necessary here since your external directory name has plenty of spaces):

```
for i in /media/ij/EXT/RNA\ seq\ data\ 2018\ Genewiz/DJ1807193/DJ1807193/*.fastq.gz;
do 
                                                       #this#  # and that, too"                       
    java -jar ~/RNAseq/trimmomatic-0.36.jar SE -phred33 "$i"   "/media/ij/EXT/trimmed/${i##*/}" ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-SE.fa:2:30:10; 
done
```